# zend 1.11.12 + modular structure + Class 'Users_Form_Login' not found

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-autoloader

I'm making my first zend application, but I have problems with the autoload of modules.
At this time I load a form that I saved in the "forms" of the form "users", but I get a "Fatal Error".
This is my configuration:

application.ini:

```
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"


resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resouces.modules = ""
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1

;my library dir
autoLoaderNameSpaces.test = "Test_"

resources.view.helperPath.Zend_View_Helper = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/default/views/helpers"

resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"
resources.layout.layout = layout
resources.view.doctype = "HTML5"
```

Dir tree:

```
application
-configs
-layouts
-modules
--default
--users
---controllers
----indexController.php -> class Users_IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
---forms
----Login.php -> class Users_Form_Login extends Zend_Form
---models
---views
---Bootstrap.php -> class Users_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap{}
--Bootstrap.php -> class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap{}
```

.
.
.

within the indexAction() of the Users_IndexController I wrote:

```
$form = new Users_Form_Login();
```

And I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Users_Form_Login' not found in [...]/application/modules/users/controllers/IndexController.php on line 39
```

**EDIT**

Class content in complement for @Tim Fountain:

Bootstrap files:

**In Bootstrap.php:**

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initActionHelpers ()
        {
            $config = $this->getOptions();
            $acl = new Test_Acl($config['acl']);
            $aclHelper = new Test_Controller_Action_Helper_Acl(null, array('acl'=>$acl));
            Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($aclHelper);

        }
}
```

**In /Users/Bootstrap.php:**

```
class Users_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{

}
```

Comment: Have you declared the class name in the form? `class Users_Form_Login extends Zend_Form { /* ... */ } `

Comment: Yes, ----Login.php -> class Users_Form_Login extends Zend_Form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each module has a bootstrap file. In the users/Bootstrap.php file have you decalred the namespace for the module?

```
  /**
   * Sets up the autoloading for this module. This function must be first in the bootstrap else other bootstrap functions might not work.
   */
  protected function _initAutoload()
  {
    $autoloader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
            'namespace' => 'Users_',
            'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH . "/modules/users",
        ));
    return $autoloader;
  }
```

Comment: The module bootstrap does this by default. You only need to create a module autoloader if you are using custom resource types.

Answer (score 1):

Your module bootstraps are not running because you have a typo in your config file:

```
resouces.modules = ""
```

should be

```
resources.modules = ""
```

then it should work.

**Edit**: In that case the first step is to see whether the bootstraps are being run. Edit your `modules/users/Bootstrap.php` class and temporarily add a method like this:

```
protected function _initTest()
{
    echo "User bootstrap run";
    exit;
}
```

reload the page in your browser and you should see that message if the bootstraps are being run. Remove it again after. If they are, then double check the filename and name of the form class (case sensitive).

Comment: I deleted the character to write it down, the server is correct, it otherwise works correctly (
The error persists, I do not know what to do...

Comment: resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules = ""
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1

Comment: Have added another test you can do to my answer.

Comment: @ Tim:So I see the page that says
  "User bootstrap run";

Comment: Do you have anything else in your users bootstrap class?

Comment: Sorry, can't see anything wrong with your code here. Either there's a typo somewhere that's not been included in what you've posted or something else elsewhere in the application is interfering with it.

Comment: I recreated all the files and now works with zf tool, though apparently it's all correct ... thank you very much